How to suppress console output from node's inbuilt test runner?
I have a test case written for the inbuilt node test runner.
const { describe, test } = require('node:test')
const assert = require('node:assert')

describe('hello', () => {
  test('can say hello', () => {
    console.log('Hello World')
    assert.equal(2 + 2, 4)
  })
})

I can run this test and it passes, gives me the summary stats, timing information, etc.
Hello World
▶ hello
  ✔ can say hello (1.157378ms)
▶ hello (2.997094ms)

ℹ tests 1
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 53.233975

My problem is I don't want the console output included. In this case it's just a one-line, "Hello World" but in my real codebase it's going to be disruptively chatty. If I was using the jest runner, I could just do --silent (or put the equivalent in the config file) and it'd go away.
What's the equivalent for node --test ? I can't see anything that looks correct in the docs (https://nodejs.org/api/test.html)
I've tried setting the test-reporter-destination to stderr and setting stdout to /dev/null but that doesn't work because the console output is part of the spec output.
Simply redirecting everything to a file doesn't work because then I don't get the summary output (i.e. what passed / failed).

Consider using a Winston logger instead of the default Node.js logger and configure it based on the environment.
When integrating Winston into your application, set it to the development environment. When running tests, switch to a testing environment where you can configure Winston to log only when using logger.error.
Alternatively, you could simply remove the console.log statements altogether. If you don't intend to see them in your console, there might not be much point in keeping them ?

I don't think that the current API offers such an option yet. As a workaround…
You could prevent test module code from writing to the stdio of your TTY by replacing process.stderr and process.stdout with disconnected Socket instances at the very start of each test entrypoint module — before importing any other code or executing any code that might write to the stdio streams.

Be sure to read the note on process I/O in the Node.js documentation.

Here's a reproducible example:
./quiet_io.mjs:
import { Socket } from "node:net";

Object.defineProperties(globalThis.process, {
  stderr: { value: new Socket() },
  stdout: { value: new Socket() },
});

./test.mjs:
// Import for side-effects only (before all other modules in the graph):
import "./quiet_io.mjs";

import * as assert from "node:assert";
import { describe, test } from "node:test";

describe("hello", () => {
  test("can say hello", () => {
    console.log("Hello World");
    assert.equal(2 + 2, 4);
  });
});

./package.json:
{
  "name": "so-78389811",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --test test.mjs"
  }
}

Test execution and output:
% node --version
v20.12.2

% npm run test

> so-78389811@0.1.0 test
> node --test test.mjs

▶ hello
  ✔ can say hello (0.576583ms)
▶ hello (1.258125ms)

ℹ tests 1
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 33.232



The answer by @jsejcksn lead me to the following solution, that I like much better because it is less intrusive. Define a customization hook like this:
// quiet-io.mjs
import { Writable } from "node:stream";

class NullStream extends Writable {
  _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    callback();
  }
}

const nullStream = new NullStream();

Object.defineProperties(process, {
  stdout: { value: nullStream, writable: false },
  stderr: { value: nullStream, writable: false },
});

And then for this test file:
// main.test.mjs
import * as assert from "node:assert";
import { describe, test } from "node:test";

describe("hello", () => {
  test("can say hello", () => {
    console.log("Hello World");
    assert.equal(2 + 2, 4);
  });
});

Compare the outputs:
$ node --test
Hello World
▶ hello
  ✔ can say hello (1.255479ms)
✔ hello (2.191132ms)
ℹ tests 1
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 67.629729
$ node --import ./quiet-io.mjs --test
✔ main.test.mjs (55.220823ms)
ℹ tests 1
ℹ suites 0
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 67.089068

This is pretty much perfect for the use case where you have multiple tests. Now I have two scripts in my package.json: test and test:silent :)
